# how to remove loading text from full screen video

Tags: google-chrome, video, fullscreen, overlay

Sometimes when viewing fullscreen video on a website, the site appears to be attempting to download a tracking pixel or some other data I don't care about in the background. Chrome wants to show me that it's "waiting for" this data with an overlay over the fullscreen video I am watching. Is there any way to turn this off? The download never seems to finish and it stays for the whole video. Screenshot below as an example:

Windows 7/10.

[image]